# looping through uitableview sections to change section header frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a grouped `UITableView` with many sections, however, I want to iterate through these sections after i tap a `UIButton`, so `viewForHeaderInSection` is useless in this case, I want to iterate through sections to change their headers frames, Im struggling to do it but to no avail until now.
I'd be grateful to anyone who helps me with this.

Comment: Why are you saying `viewForHeaderInSection` is useless ? Could you describe what you have already tried ?

Comment: viewForHeaderInSection will set up the view for uitableview header at first time the table view loads, but after that I can't use this method to re-set the frame of the section header (during runtime).

Comment: No you can, just change the model that has generated a header, then do [table reloadData];

Comment: You might be able to call myTableView beginUpdates on button press after you change the frames of headerViews

Comment: @JAHelia Oh, really ? Did you really tried to use `viewForHeaderInSection` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewForHeaderInSection` gets called every time you call `ReloadData` on a table view.
So you could have a Boolean that gets set to yes every time your button is pressed, and also call reloadData in the button's action. In viewForHeaderInSection, check the value of the bool, if it's true, set the size to what you want when the button is pressed, if false set it to the normal size.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After you header view's datasource iterated and changed in whichever you wish way, call

```
[mytable reloadData]
```

And your header views are redrawn. Simple and clearly you have not tried that before asking, next time do it.